# Does Codename one support Split Pane UI component?

Tags: split, codenameone, pane

I take a look into all classes which are supported by Codename One and don't see any class which have spell like "Split". Does Codename One support a UI component like Java Swing Split Pane -https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/splitpane.html?

Answer (score 0):

That UI element doesn't make much sense in a touch device or mobile phone so it was never implemented. There are many potential replacements for common use cases of the split pane.

E.g. we use the side menu of the toolbar to place collapsable elements we'd like to work with.

You can probably implement this UX by adding 3 components to a TableLayout container with varying width/height constraints to allow the split pane look (the middle component would be the split). E.g. the middle component can be a button styled as the split where you override the `pointerDragged()` callback to remove and re-add the cells withmodify the new width constraint and then `revalidate()`.